# Resolving Maven conflict: jBoss AS 7 duplicate Antlr jar exclussion from POM for JUnit runner

Tags: hibernate, maven, junit, jboss7.x, antlr

I am running into an issue building for `JUnit` when I exclude `Antlr` from the `hibernate-entitymanager` dependency declaration in the POM file.

I had to exclude `Antlr` since it seems like `JBoss AS 7` is introducing its own copy of the jar file. After I add the exclusion I am able to build and deploy to `JBoss` just fine, but I am not able to run the unit tests unless I manually remove the exclusion.

Below is the relevant section of the POM file.

What is the best way to solve this issue or tell Maven to not exclude `Antlr` when running in `JUnit`?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <!-- Exclude antlr since it conflicts with Jboss AS7 
    <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
       <groupId>antlr</groupId>
       <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
    </exclusions>  -->
</dependency>
```

Comment: Specify hibernate dependencies as provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ctomc's suggestion, I used this solution which worked for me. Thanks again!

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <!-- Exclude antlr since it conflicts with Jboss AS7   -->
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```